# Stop the knob from rotating past xyz degrees and prevent it from rotating backward from 0 degrees

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know how to make this code stop the knob from rotating past xyz degrees for example stopping the rotation at 340 degrees instead of going the full 360 so you can't keep turning it around constantly? I'm trying to make a turnable knob. It works but currently it's not clamped so someone can keep turning it in a complete circle forward and backward. I want to prevent it from doing that so there is a min and max value.

```
- (void)rotating:(KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    [self doRotation:recognizer.rotation];    
    [recognizer setRotation:0];
}

- (void)doRotation:(float)rot {

    CGFloat theAngle = atan2(knob.transform.b, knob.transform.a);

    float temp_var = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(theAngle);

    if(temp_var < 0) temp_var = 360 - fabs(temp_var);

    float percent = (temp_var / 315) * 100;
    float val = ((float)(percent))/100;

    knob.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([knob transform], rot);

    if(percent < 100 && percent > 0) { 
        display.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.f", percent];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a rotatable knob example that you can download. It does exactly what you describe.

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/blob/master/convertedToIOS5/p618p635knob/p618p635knob/MyKnob.m

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much! One question though. Can I set the angle? For example if the current angle it should be is 3.5?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can modify the example however you like. The "0" and "5" limit used throughout is arbitrary.

Comment: Well what I mean is um setting a default value? um lets say you rotate the knob then exit the application it will remember the rotation and set it back to where it last was when you open the app again.

Comment: An easier way to say it would be to set the angle programmatically?

Comment: The example has given you an angle property you can set. I don't see what else you're asking for. But anyhow it's only an example! I'm just showing you how to get started; writing actual code is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to stop the rotation if it's greater than 340°? Just check if `temp_var` is greater than 340 and then return out of the method. You should also consider renaming that to `degrees` or something more obvious as to what it is.

```
if(temp_var < 0) temp_var = 360 - fabs(temp_var);
// add this next line:
if (temp_var > 340) { return; }

float percent = (temp_var / 315) * 100;
```

Comment: Tried it but when I get to 340° I can't rotate it counterclockwise it's just locked at 340°